# How can a debug flavor variant depend on a release code

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm publishing a multi-module Android library. The use case is that I want to run a sample app (in debug) against the release AARs (that are proguarded) of my library. The ultimate goal is to be able to test the exact artifacts what would be published.

My modules and their desired build types are:

```
:my-library (release)
:mock-server (debug)
:sample (debug)
```

`:sample` depends on `:my-library` and `:mock-server`. `:mock-server` also depends on `:my-library`.

To achieve this, I set up a flavor dimension:

```
android {
  flavorDimensions "SOURCE_OR_BINARY"

  productFlavors {
    source {
      // indicates that project dependencies are used directly
    }
    binary {
      // dependencies added via here will be AARs
    }
}

dependencies{
  binaryImplementation(name: ':my-library', ext: 'aar')
  sourceImplementation project(':my-library')
  implementation project(':mock-server')
}

task prepareBinaryDependencies(dependsOn: [
        ":my-library:assembleRelease" // to generate AARs
]) {}

//
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    def taskName = task.name.toLowerCase()
    if (taskName.toLowerCase().contains("binary")) {
        // Prepare libs as binaries
        task.dependsOn prepareBinaryDependencies
        task.doFirst {
            prepareBinaryDependencies
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine with `./gradlew` on the command line, but Android Studio often reports a `Failed to resolve: :my-library-release:` during gradle sync. If I do a `./gradlew assemble` on the command line, **then** sync Android Studio, the the AS Gradle sync succeeds.

It seems that I am doing something wrong here. Is there a way to do this better that will avoid the `Failed to resolve` Android Studio Gradle sync error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to resolve local AAR built from local source module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53340361/failed-to-resolve-local-aar-built-from-local-source-module)