# Failed to resolve local AAR built from local source module

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a library module that I want to include as an AAR dependency into a sample app:

```
:my-library
:sample-app
```

So in `sample/build.gradle`, I do the following:

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs "../my-library/build/outputs/aar" 
    }
}

// I have different flavors that specify whether to use the source or binary (aar) dependency

flavorDimensions "SOURCE_OR_BINARY"
    productFlavors {
        source { }
        binary { }
}

dependencies {
    sourceImplementation project(':my-library')
    binaryImplementation(name: 'my-library-release', ext: 'aar') // <-- this line fails with error
}

tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    def taskName = task.name.toLowerCase()
    if (taskName.toLowerCase().contains("binary")) {
        // Prepare libs as binaries
        task.dependsOn ('my-library:assembleRelease')
    }
}
```

This works fine with `./gradlew` on the command line, but Android Studio reports a `Failed to resolve: :my-library-release:` during gradle sync. If I do a `./gradlew assemble` on the command line, **then** sync Android Studio, the the AS Gradle sync succeeds.

The issue has to do with the timing of `binaryImplementation(name: 'my-library-release', ext: 'aar')`. When Gradle Sync is executed, the `aar` does not exist yet because it has yet to be built.

Is there a better way to do this that will avoid the `Failed to resolve` Android Studio Gradle sync error?

Comment: Are you sure there isn't any other task that contains 'binary'?

Comment: Are you are building an Android lib along with the application? If YES, I would suggest adding the lib module as a dependency from Project settings window. And once your lib is ready for production you can build aar from lib module and you can add to the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer can be found here - expose a configuration with that AAR, and consume that configuration downstream

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/cross_project_publications.html

Answer (score 3):

You need to add this to your app main build.gradle.

```
    repositories {
          /...
          /...
         flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
```

Lets say if you .aar file in the lib folder,then you could do something like this.

```
implementation files('libs/assembleRelease.aar')
```

Comment: this still fails. When Gradle Sync is executed, the aar does not exist yet because it has yet to be built.

`Unable to resolve dependency for ':sample@binaryDebug/compileClasspath': Failed to transform file 'my-library-release.aar' to match attributes {artifactType=processed-aar} using transform IdentityTransform`

Answer (score 2):

You can try import with this way,

File -> New Module -> Import .Jar/.AAR package

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you use a local maven repository rather that flatDir. Dependencies which come from FileCollection and/or flatDir are not as full-featured as those coming from a "real" repository (eg maven/ivy)

Eg:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url file("${rootProject.projectDir}/mavenRepo") 
    } 
} 
dependencies {
    binaryImplementation "my-group:my-artifact:1.0@aar"
    ... 
}
```

You'd then store the artifact using the [maven repository directory layout](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVENOLD/Repository+Layout+-+Final). Eg:

```
rootProject/mavenRepo/my-group/my-artifact/1.0/my-artifact-1.0.aar
```

Comment: Once these two issues are implemented, then I can try this approach. I don't know if this issue will occur again when the artifact does not exist in the maven repo at gradle-sync time? but does exist after build time?

Comment: Why people didn't vote up this answer? It helps me!